# Why Can't I Add Google Font Families In cPanel Branding Editor?

Tags: cpanel, theme

I'm working on my own cPanel x3 theme. I've edited the stdheader.html file and have added this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis|Roboto+Condensed|Vollkorn" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

These are font families and font awesome. However, it just doesn't take. There are no errors in my Chrome console, but they also don't seem to be called. In others words that code is being ignored, and is not showing up in the source code. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: >> Can someone tell me why? - No, with this much information we can't. We need more.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards there's nothing more to tell.

Comment: It's likely not reporting because there's nothing too report. You should ensure that all traces of the old 'font-family' is removed and replaced with the new... Also you should be able to get more of an idea whats going on by using firebug, inspect the element see what font is being called, and then check in the .net panel to see if Google's font is being downloaded, if not then you can download the font from Google and host locally.

Comment: @Xarcell You say >> it just doesn't take. - Can we take a look at your theme? Have you debugged your theme yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the link is not showing in your source code (view the source via your browser to confirm this), then cPanel will be stripping the tag *before* it makes it to the screen, which is why your console will not show any errors.

My hunch would be that it is a security measure to prevent potential XSS issues.  Security is going to be a major concern to cPanel, and I imagine bespoke styling far less so.

Comment: I was gonna ask over at cpanel forums, but I can't login and there is no "forgot password" link.

Comment: @Xarcell There is... http://forums.cpanel.net/login.php?do=lostpw

Comment: It does seem as though they are being stripped out. I can see it in the source code when in the branding editor itself, but not when a user views cpanel.